# zip problem in shell script . Why it is wrong?

Tags: shell-script, zip

Write a shell script file_locker.sh to zip a file and protect such with a hashed password of a random generated PIN of specified length, while storing the PIN to a specified file.

```
#!/bin/bash
file_locker(){

m=$1
for ((i=1;i<=m;i++));
do
num=($(( 0 + RANDOM % 9 )))

echo -n "$num"

done > $3

mypin=$(echo $3)
echo pin $mypin

myhash=$(echo $mypin | sha256sum)
echo hash $myhash

zip -P $myhash $2.zip -r $2 && rm $2

}
file_locker $1 $2 $3
```

However, command line tells me like that:

```
zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot write zip file to terminal)
```

I don't how to improve the zip command.
please help !

Answer (score 1):

you should use quotes in arguments...
and use $m instead of m in for loop

```
#!/bin/bash
file_locker(){

m="$1"
for ((i=1;i<=$m;i++));
do
num=($(( 0 + RANDOM % 9 )))

echo -n "$num"

done > "$3"

mypin=$(echo "$3")
echo pin "$mypin"

myhash=$(echo "$mypin" | sha256sum)
echo hash "$myhash"

zip -P "$myhash" "$2".zip -r "$2" && rm "$2"

}
file_locker "$1" "$2" "$3"
```

> zip error: Invalid command arguments ..

you will get this if your argument has spaces in it...